# bootstrap carousel slide control not respond

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

Am i creating multiple html pages, where index.html consist of the bootstrap carousel which slided through some couple of images and am i connecting all the html pages through ngroute,The problem is when loading the carousel in index.html if click the next or prev button in the carousel it just navigating to the another html page or it's same page,i hereby paste a working plunker link for reference: 
 Please help me to resolve this issues.

```
Am i creating multiple html pages, where index.html consist of the bootstrap carousel which slided through some couple of images and am i connecting all the html pages through ngroute,The problem is when loading the carousel in index.html if click the next or prev button in the carousel it just navigating to the another html page or it's same page,i hereby paste a working plunker link for reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/VUS8RjQkVQabEBxRWMdB?p=info Please help me to resolve this issues.
```

Comment: hereby paste a working plunker link for reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/VUS8RjQkVQabEBxRWMdB?p=info Please help me to resolve this issues.

Comment: It's better to provide some codes to see if something goes wrong. Besides, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this in your main controller

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
  $scope.isIndexPage = $location.path() === '/';
});
```